# Java JPA. Select column from other table using where by other column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity, where-clause

I have two tables:

```
create table table_binding (id bigint not null, description varchar(255),primary key (id));
```

and

```
create table table2 (id bigint not null, value clob, type varchar(255));
```

For example tables has been filled with next values:

table_binding:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |    Description   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |     Some Desc    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |    Other Desc    |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

table2:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |       value      |       type       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |      VALUE_A     |       TYPE1      | 
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |      VALUE_B     |       TYPE2      | 
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |      VALUE_C     |       TYPE1      | 
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |      VALUE_D     |       TYPE2      | 
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I have single entity like

```
@Entity(name = "table_binding")
@Data
public class myBinding(){

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    Long id; 
    private String description;
    @Clob
    private String value1;
    @Clob
    private String value2;

}
```

How can i modify entity class code to make values1 and value2 be the same as returning values of next sql query:
value1:

```
select value.t2 from table2 t2,table_binding t1 where t2.type="TYPE1" and t2.id=t1.id and t1.id=?
```

value2:

```
select value.t2 from table2 t2,table_binding t1 where t2.type="TYPE2" and t2.id=t1.id and t1.id=?
```

I mean that myBinding entity for id=1 will be:
id =1 ;descripton ="Some Desc"; valu1="VALUE_A" ;value2="VALUE_B"

I know about @SecondaryTable and @Column annotation, but they do not let implement

```
where t2.type="TYPE1"
```

Answer (score 0):

The entities have to be a faithful representation of the database.

According to the configuration that you choose, the application does not lift since you are indicating in the entity that the TABLE_BINDING table has the columns VALUE1 and VALUE2 when it does not.

The best thing you can do is model two entities, one for each table with its respective columns and implement a query that returns the data you want, either with an fk between the two or with a subquery or adding the two tables to the from. and the necessary conditions to the where clause to avoid the Cartesian product, not touching the entities.